# Two different formulas for determining the angle in polar coordinate system

Tags: polar-coordinates

Given a coordinate $\left(x,y\right)$ in Cartesian system ,where $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and $r^{2}=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$.

I've seen lots of formulas for calculating $\theta$,Wikipedia states the angle $\theta$ is calculated by the following formula:

$${\displaystyle \varphi ={\begin{cases}\arccos \left({\frac {x}{r}}\right)&{\mbox{if }}y\geq 0{\mbox{ and }}r\neq 0\\-\arccos \left({\frac {x}{r}}\right)&{\mbox{if }}y<0\\{\text{undefined}}&{\mbox{if }}r=0.\end{cases}}}$$

This reference states the angle $\theta$ is calculated by

$$\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \;\;\text{if}\;\; x>0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\pi  \;\;\text{if}\;\; x<0 \text{ and } y \ge 0$$

However these two are should give the same answer, consider the coordinate $\left(4,-3\right)$.

One gives $-\arccos\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)$, the other gives $\arctan\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)$,which are **not** the same.(I assumed $r\le0$) and the real answer is $\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$.

Can someone explain why the answers are not the same?and give me a formula which work for all conditions?

---

The question comes from Thomas calculus book

[image]

Comment: To @number: $r$ represents a distance from a reference point...

Comment: I am very confused. What is $\varphi?$ I have not seen this before. But it is correct that $\theta$ is calculated in the manner you describe, so for the coordinate $(4, -3),$ we have that $x > 0,$ so we should use $\theta= \arctan \bigl(\frac{y}{x} \bigr) = \arctan \bigl( \frac{-3}{4} \bigr).$

Comment: @  Anton Vrdoljak ,In my opinion $r$ should be always positive or zero,since it represents distance,however Thomas calculus book has totally ruined my imagination about distance ,I see that in the book $r$ can be negative ,and this issue confused me a lot,and I don't see any formula which works for $r$ negative.

Comment: @number Indeed $r\ge0$ always, so in this case $r=5$. See also my answer.

Comment: Also, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) are some more formulae that work.

Answer (score 1):

No, the first formula gives $-\arccos\frac45$. Indeed$$x=4,\,y=-3<0\implies r=5,\,\varphi=-\arccos\frac{x}{r}.$$

Comment: @  J.G,thanks for the answer,so $r$ negative is meaningless,can you tell me why the book lets $r$ to be negative?

Comment: @mnumber Can you quote Thomas allowing $r<0$?

Comment: I will post an image,look at it

Comment: @ J.G.,where  does the real answer come from?

Comment: @number The formulae are equivalent, but they all need $r\ge0$ (in fact, $r>0$ to get $\varphi$). I think Thomas had a typo. If $\le$ were intentional, which would be surprising, you'd have to multiply $x,\,y$ by $-1$, then solve subject to $r\ge0$.